# python - converting groups of rows in 1 column to columns

Tags: python, excel, transform

I am new to Python and I have a requirement where I need to transform groups of rows into columns in excel. Following is a sample dataset.

```
Rachel
42
female

Bob
49
male
```

I need these to be transformed into columns.

```
Rachel 42   female
Bob    49   mail
```

I read about pandas. But I am not sure how to use it as there is a line between the groups of data and it does not have defined column headers either. If anyone could guide, that would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose the file name is `your_data.csv`. You can find load the data using pandas: `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)`. Then reshape the dataframe to `N x 3`, where `N` is the number of unique user. For example, for Name you can do as: `'Name': df.iloc[::3, 0].reset_index(drop=True),` etc.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I got the Name. How do I get age? It should start from 2nd row for age.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Nick Nick Nick suggestion and some reading, I got it to produce the transformed columns. Following is the script.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/report_2.csv', header=None)

name_series = df.iloc[::3, 0].reset_index(drop=True)
name_series = pd.Series(name_series, name = 'Name')

age_series = df.iloc[1:, 0].reset_index(drop=False)
age_series = age_series.iloc[::3, 1]
age_series = pd.Series(age_series.reset_index(drop=True), name = 'Age')

gender_series = df.iloc[2:, 0].reset_index(drop=False)
gender_series = gender_series.iloc[::3, 1]
gender_series = pd.Series(gender_series.reset_index(drop=True), name = 'Gender')

horizontal_concat_df = pd.concat([name_series, age_series, gender_series], axis=1)
horizontal_concat_df.index.name = 'Num'

horizontal_concat_df.to_csv('data\convert_result_2.csv', sep=',')
```

Please suggest if there is a better approach. The actual data has 52 rows of similar data in a single column, so I will need to create 52 series for my script to fulfill the requirement.

Thanks,
Reet